# Почему интерпретатор не может импортировать объекты из файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

у меня есть директория с вот такой структурой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файл choise_button.py содержит в себе 2 объекта

```
choise_role = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
[
    InlineKeyboardButton(text = "Я учитель", callback_data="teacher"),
    InlineKeyboardButton(text = "Я ученик", callback_data="student")
],
[
    InlineKeyboardButton(text = "Отмена", callback_data="cancel")
]
])

choise_name = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
[
    InlineKeyboardButton(text = "Отмена", callback_data="cancel"),
]
])
```

Я пытаюсь импортировать эти объекты в файл heandler

```
from choice_button import choise_role, choise_name
```

Но интерпретатор не видит объект choise_name и выдает ошибку (объект choise_role виден)

> from choice_button import choise_role, choise_name

Как это исправить?

Comment: А какая ошибка? Запуск скрипта выполняется из папки на скриншоте? По идеи, проблем с импортом тут не должно быть

Comment: Опечатка либо в Вашем вопросе, либо, что скорее всего, является причиной ошибки. Файл у Вас называется choi**s**e_button.py, а импортируете Вы из choi**c**e_button. К слову, с точки зрения английского языка, правильный вариант второй, через "c".

Comment: @V-Mor нет, на картинке со структурой папки правильное название файла

Comment: Покажите полный текст ошибки и ввод/вывод команды выполнения (добавьте в сам вопрос)

Comment: а если попробовать `from .choice_button import choise_role, choise_name` ?

Comment: Возможно, где-то опечатка в "choise_name"? Например, вместо английской "c" написали русскую "c".