# Проблема с импортом модулей из верхних директорий

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

МОй проект имеет вот такую структуру файлов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файле, который находится внутри директории heandlers я пытаюсь импортировать класс содержащийся в файле FSM.py

Строка импорта

```
StudentMenu `from FSM import OrderRegistration, StudentMenu`
```

Содержимое FSM.py

```
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup


    class OrderRegistration(StatesGroup):
        waiting_for_name = State()
        waiting_for_role = State()
    
    
    class StudentMenu(StatesGroup):
        action selection = State()
```

При импорте я получаю ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anton/dev/Bots/EnglishGitBot/app.py", line 16, in <module>
    from heandlers import dp
  File "/home/anton/dev/Bots/EnglishGitBot/heandlers/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import database_heandler, message_heandler, inline_heandler
  File "/home/anton/dev/Bots/EnglishGitBot/heandlers/message_heandler.py", line 10, in <module>
    from FSM import OrderRegistration, StudentMenu
ImportError: cannot import name 'StudentMenu' from 'FSM' (/home/anton/dev/Bots/EnglishGitBot/FSM.py)
```

Почему я не могу импортировать класс StudentMenu, в то время как класс OrderRegistration прекрасно импортируется?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1168153/398802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вот это у вас нормально вообще компилируется? Мне кажется, ошибка здесь.

```
class StudentMenu(StatesGroup):
    action selection = State()
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ что это?
```